# Binding listview column to a property of an objects collection separated from this collection. Attaching a property to EF6-generated class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, xaml

I have some trouble with binding a column of ListView/GridView to a property.
I usef Entity Framework 6 to generate model classes ("patient" for instance). Something like that:

```
 public patient()
    {
        email_patients = new HashSet<email_patients>();
        medical_records = new HashSet<medical_records>();
        phones_patients = new HashSet<phones_patients>();
        patients_tag = new HashSet<patients_tag>();
    }
```

I tried to create additinal Age property in the class and then calculate it for every object using foreeach loop in this constructor. I've failed because of an error "invalid column name" or something like that. I suppose I had to get a column in the database table with the same name (?) but I want to calculate at runtime. So I use ViewModel class to calculate age.

```
 class PatientsMainListUserControlViewModel
{
    private ObservableCollection<patient> _patients;
    public ObservableCollection<patient> patients
    {
        get { return _patients; }
        set { _patients = value; }
    }
    List<int> ages = new List<int>();
    
    internal PatientsMainListUserControlViewModel()
    {
        using (var db = new MainEntityModel())
        {
            patients = new ObservableCollection<patient>(db.patients);
        }
       
        foreach (patient p in patients)
        {
        int age = p.birthdate.Year - DateTime.Now.Year;

        if (DateTime.Now.Month < p.birthdate.Month)
        {
            age = age - 1;
        }

        else if (DateTime.Now.Month == p.birthdate.Month && DateTime.Now.Day < p.birthdate.Day)
        {
            age = age - 1;
        }
            ages.Add(age);
        }
        patients.Add(ages);
    }
```

The problem is a can't add "ages" list to "patients" ObservableCollection (cannot convert error appears). And a column of a listview can't be attached to a property of another source (view model's list) than the listview itself. I've tried different approaches and have read everything Google found for me. At the moment my xaml is foolowing:

```
  <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Surname" Width="100" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding surname}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding name}"></GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Age" Width="70" x:Name="agescolumn">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ages}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                
            </GridView>
```

How can I display a property calculated in hard-code approach for an observable collection I can't interfere? I suppose it is wrong approach because this ages list don't really becomes a property of a patient object.
I would appretiate your help.

Comment: You can't just add properties to objects at runtime.  You need to change the object definition to add the property.  If you don't want the property to map to a column in the database you can mark it with a `[NotMapped]` attribute.

Comment: Thanks, David. My insoluble problem resolved pretty easy!